# ARCore: Get the 3D coordinates of all detected points

Tags: java, arcore

I’m programming an app for point cloud detection with ARCore in Java.

I want to get the 3D coordinates of all points, which are rendered in the frames. Currently I get only a very few of these points, if I use the following code.

```
 pointCloud = frame.acquirePointCloud();
      if (list1 != null) {
      String x = String.valueOf(df.format(pointCloud.getPoints().get(0))).replace(",", ".");
      String y = String.valueOf(df.format(pointCloud.getPoints().get(1))).replace(",", ".");
      String z = String.valueOf(df.format(pointCloud.getPoints().get(2))).replace(",", ".");
      String c = String.valueOf(df.format(pointCloud.getPoints().get(3))).replace(",", ".");

      list1.add(x + ", " + y + ", " + z + ", " + c + "\n");
  }
```

I only found one other implementation. I tried this one, but I got a lot of confusing points, which drifted away.

```
pointCloud = frame.acquirePointCloud();
if (list6 != null) {
    FloatBuffer fb = pointCloud.getPoints();
    while (fb.hasRemaining()) {
      float x = Float.parseFloat(df.format(fb.get()).replace(",", "."));
      float y = Float.parseFloat(df.format(fb.get()).replace(",", "."));
      float z = Float.parseFloat(df.format(fb.get()).replace(",", "."));
      float c = Float.parseFloat(df.format(fb.get()).replace(",", "."));

        list6.add(x + ", " + y + ", " + z + ", " + c + "\n");
    }
  }
```

I´m not sure that it is a problem in the code.
Does sombody have a better idea to get all points or can tell me what I’m doing wrong?

I would be glad about some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code for acquiring Point Cloud data. You can check the length of Point Cloud Ids array to know the exact number of Point Clouds.

Using the below code you can map the Point Data to exact ID and be sure if all the data is available.

```
    PointCloud pointCloud = frame.acquirePointCloud();
    IntBuffer pointCloudIds = pointCloud.getIds();
    int[] pointCloudIdsArray = new int[pointCloudIds.limit()];
    pointCloudIds.get(pointCloudIdsArray);

    Log.i(TAG, "onDrawFrame: Point Cloud Id Array Length " + 
    pointCloudIdsArray.length);

    FloatBuffer pointCloudData = pointCloud.getPoints();

    float[] pointCloudArray = new float[pointCloudData.limit()];
    pointCloudData.get(pointCloudArray);

    Log.i(TAG, "onDrawFrame: Point Cloud Data Array Length " + pointCloudArray.length);

    long PointCloudTimeStamp = pointCloud.getTimestamp();

    if (pointCloudIdsArray.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < pointCloudIdsArray.length; i++) {

            Log.i("TAG",Long.toString(PointCloudTimeStamp) + ";" +
            Integer.toString(pointCloudIdsArray[i]) + ";" +
            Float.toString(pointCloudArray[i * 4]) + ";" +
            Float.toString(pointCloudArray[i * 4 + 1]) + ";" +
            Float.toString(pointCloudArray[i * 4 + 2]) + ";" +
            Float.toString(pointCloudArray[i * 4 + 3]) + "\n");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it and the result is the same like my second code.

Comment: Try in a different area or perhaps a brighter area with many objects laying around. The Point Cloud provided by ArCore is not of very high quality as in you will always get limited points. Basic purpose to provide point cloud is help debugging rather than to use it for purposes like 3D modelling.